# errorcode:1064 when filtering members based on age

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-error-1064

I want to get the people whose age is between these two values (suppose for example I want to filter out the people aged between 18 and 24).

This is the Member table structure:

```
 member_id 
 member_firstname 
 member_dob(datatype is string) (values like 1987-09-08,1976-09-08,.....)
```

i am using mysql as my database.....

```
SELECT members.member_Id,
               members.member_Lastname as 'Last Name',
               members.member_Firstname as 'First Name',
               members.member_Postcode as 'Post Code',
               members.member_Reference as Reference,
               members.member_CardNum as 'Card Number',
               members.member_IsBiometric as Biometric,
               members.member_DOB as DoB,
               mshiptypes.mshipType_Name as Membership,
               mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name as Status,
               membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate as Expiry
                 FROM members
INNER JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id
 INNER JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id
INNER JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id
INNER JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipStatusTypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id
WHERE memberToMship_EndDate BETWEEN '2011-09-24' AND '2011-09-30'
AND members.member_active LIKE 'y%'
AND (YEAR(CURDATE(members.member_Dob))-YEAR()) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)< RIGHT(member_Dob,5)) BETWEEN '21' AND '102'
ORDER BY members.member_Lastname
```

got an error like this.....

```
     Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'member_Dob))-YEAR()) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)< RIGHT(member_Dob,5)) BETWEEN '21' AN' at line 19
```

modified :

```
               SELECT members.member_Id,
                   members.member_Lastname as 'Last Name',
                   members.member_Firstname as 'First Name',
                   members.member_Postcode as 'Post Code',
                   members.member_Reference as Reference,
                   members.member_CardNum as 'Card Number',
                   members.member_IsBiometric as Biometric,
                   members.member_DOB as DoB,
                   mshiptypes.mshipType_Name as Membership,
                   mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name as Status,
                   membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate as Expiry
                     FROM members
    INNER JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id
     INNER JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id
    INNER JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id
    INNER JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipStatusTypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id
    WHERE memberToMship_EndDate BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-16'
    AND members.member_active LIKE 'y%'
    AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(member_Dob)
 - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(member_Dob,5)) BETWEEN '18' AND '109'
    ORDER BY members.member_Lastname




  error:


 **

Error Code: 1064
        You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY members.member_Lastname' at line 21
```

**

Comment: The YEAR function has a compulsory argument.

Comment: I don't think `CURDATE` accepts any parameter? It returns current date only??

Comment: Why isn't `member_dob` a `DATE` field?

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ by default it is string datatype i cant change the schema....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) takes a `date` argument
2. [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) takes no arguments.

Change that `AND` clause to:

```
AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(member_Dob, '%Y-%m-%d'))
     - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(member_Dob,5))) BETWEEN 21 AND 102
```

Note that you might not need [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) if you have it stored as YYYY-MM-DD but I would use it anyways to be on the safe side. The condition below should also work:

```
AND (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(member_Dob)
     - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(member_Dob,5))) BETWEEN 21 AND 102
```

Comment: would you pls take a look at my modified query and i got an error .

Comment: @error I'm sorry, it's missing a right parenthesis

Comment: would you pls suggest any idea to do this.. so that i will give any value between 1 to 120 ....

Comment: @error What? And have you added the right parens? It should at least fix the syntax error.